# How to Sqoop Import data from Different Data base in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

```
$cat > import.txt
    import
    --connect
    jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopdb
    --username
    hadoop
    -password
    abc
```

In a txt file I have kept the jdbc url, username and password in one text file and when I call a sqoop command I call it as follows:

```
sqoop --options-file /user/cloudera/import.txt --table employee
```

But I want to import from multiple database into HDFS. How shall I approach the same for multiple database?
I tried searching for the same but dint get any proper resource. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by writing a shell script with multiple sqoop statements. One sqoop statement per job. You could have each statement within the shell script reference it's own options file.

Comment: So you mean for every database I have to write the sqoop statement with their reference? 
Actually the problem is for one database itself I have around 15 sqoop statements as we need to import few tables from the data base. It would be easier if the references were looped and the 15 statements are made to run.

Comment: You could create a loop inside the shell script and accomplish this. [hortonworks link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/29298/i-want-to-import-certain-tables-from-multiple-sql.html) describes what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create workflow.xml for sqoop action by parameterise  each fields e.g.
import
    --connect
    jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopdb
    --username
    hadoop
    -password
    abc

--connect
    $(connection_string)
    --username
    $(user_name) 
    --password-file
    (password_file_path)
    --table
    $(table_name)

And assign value of each variable in job.properties file and run it thru Oozie commands:
oozie job -oozie http://XXXX.XX.iroot.adidom.com:XXXX/oozie -config job.properties -run
you can also schedule it thru coordinator.xml

Thanks,